# How do I turn Jute scrap into Jute bolts?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Since I can't seem to find the answer anywhere, but I'm sure lots have done this, how do I convert **Jute Scrap** into **Jute Bolts** ? I have like 30 of these now, and want to craft.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the crafting interface, under refinements, there is a recipe for converting scrap into bolts.

Comment: Thanks! I figured I was missing something easy. I'll mark the answer in 9 min when it lets me.

Comment: Note that this only applies to Armorsmith, Leatherworker, and Tailor.